# which kind of normalized gene expression matrix is suitable for cor, cor.test or corr.test

Tags: r, statistics, normalization

I decided to use corr.test to calculate the correlation between genes.

And I know the input object must be a matrix or dataframe. But I don't think it's a vital part for me to pay attention to.

Now what confuses me is I don't know  which kind of normalized gene expression matrix is suitable for corr.test.  I think the FPKM gene counts  after t() is suitable before. But I don't think so after somebody told me something about vst-transformed counts ？

Can somebody give me some advice ？ Now I have the FPKM value and corr.test .If I need to change my normalization method ?

Comment: This question is probably more suitable for biostars.

Answer (score 0):

FPKM is normalized data, so first you can apply log transform and transform the matrix to vectorized format taking transpose for statistical analysis. if you want to use count data, for VST is good option with Deseq2 package in R.